# Unable to Find RPi on Network w/ New Router

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet, connection

I recently got a new router at home and have been unable to find my Raspberry Pi on the network. Comcast sent me a new router to replace an aging one. My Pi does not show up in the list of connected devices in the router homepage and I was unable to find it by scanning the network with nmap. I noticed my new router uses a different numbering system to assign IP addresses - for example, 10.0.0.8 instead of 192.168.1.8, which I am used to. I used to have the Pi set up with a static IP address and DDNS redirect so I could SSH into it from school. Could it be that the settings in /etc/network/interfaces for the old router are preventing a connection with the new one?

This is frustrating since I don't have a USB keyboard or mouse with which to connect with the Pi. So SSH is my primary means to using it. I might have to invest in some peripherals now...

Comment: *"I might have to invest in some peripherals now"* -> I know it is not the same everywhere, but a generic USB keyboard + mouse seems unlikely to go over $15 in the modern west.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you got new numbering for the private network when getting new router. If that is the case, that is also the reason why you can't find the Raspberry Pi on the network.

You might use UTP cable to connect Raspberry Pi with your PC and set the proper network address (e.g. 10.0.0.2 - from your example) on the PC to get access to Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be clear: Is your RPi on a wired or wireless network? If it's wireless and you didn't configure your new router with the exact same wireless settings, you will have to connect it via a wired connection and try to locate it. Plugging an Ethernet cable from your RPi to the router should work, assuming the router hands out DHCP addresses and your RPi is still using DHCP for the Ethernet interface.

If you RPi is using a wired network connection and you hard coded the IP information, just plug a PC into that same network and configure it also with a hard coded IP address in the same range, then locate it using nmap. Multiple IP subnets can co-exist on the same network/switch.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file directly. To mount the SD-card properly, you need to do it on a linux machine. It should work, because I've done it several times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Raspbian, IP address can be assigned in the file

> cmdline.txt

which was created in the sd card,, when raspbian image was burnt in to it.

Insert the sd card in your PC. Look for `cmdline.txt` file in the sd card.
At the end of this file add `ip=10.0.0.X`, where 10.0.0.X is any ip address, which have not been yet assigned to any device by your router.

> All the text in the `cmdline` file should be in single line. There shouldn't be any line break.

After saving the `cmdline`txt file, boot the Pi with the sd card. SSH to this ip address (putty!!). It should able to work.
Take backup (in case...)